# how to get the key value of a dictionary in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, backend

i have a dictionary of list of dictionary in my view.py

```
...
data = {'item':[{'key1':'value' ,'key2':'value2' ,'key3':'value3'}]}
...
```

in my template i want to get the value of the key of the `item` dictionry,

i can get the elements in the `item` dictionary.
 but how can i get the key value of the elements of my item dictionary in a for loop in my template
like this:

```
{% for items in item %}
    <li>{{item|first}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: `item` is not a dictionary, it's a list

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `data` is the context you pass to your template, get the keys like

```
{% for d in item %}  # item is list of dicts
  {% for key, value in d.items %} 
    <li>{{ key }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

`d` is the the dictionary since `item` itself is a `list`. The rest is just looping over [`dict.items`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Comment: it's just returning the first element of the key value of the 0 element of my list,but i want to have all element .

Comment: this only return the 0 element in list but i want all elements  in my list to be printed.how should i do that?! @schwobaseggl

Comment: Well, just iterate over the dicts in `item` and do the same for each of them

Answer (score 2):

You can just access the keys using the standard Python `keys` method:

```
{% for dict in item %}
    {% for key in dict.keys %}
        <li>{{ key }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively you can get both the keys and the values using the standard Python `items` method:

```
{% for dict in item %}
    {% for key, value in dict.items %}
        <li>{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: both methods don't work for me.i have tried it befor but won't work:(

Comment: Oh you're quite right, I misread your post. I've updated the answer.